# iOS app is showing crash on firebase crashlytics

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting crashes on the live app. **libquic.dylib
qlog_abort_internal + 272**

[image]

Comment: Have you handled internet connection while calling api?

Comment: Yes. Before calling the API, i am checking the internet state.@HarikarthickK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is a know issue in iOS 15 and iPadOS 15. There is a current thread where they are stating it has been resolved in iOS 15.2, so updating OS should avoid this issue. Unfortunately, no workarounds have been provided as of yet. [You can see the thread here.](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693245)

Comment: Having it on iOS 15.5 too.